# Background process in C

Tags: c, windows, process

How do I make a process go the background in C?
I know how to do that in UNIX but how to do it in Windows ?

What I want is for the user to double-click the process executable, and it just goes into the background ... and does not open a window while executing.

I'm not looking for complete solution just a reference.
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ChikaneHimeko has already stated create a Windows application that has no windows:

```
#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    Sleep(5000); /* Just here to illustrate not visible but running */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a Windows application that does not show a window.

Answer (score 0):

[look at this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) CreateProcess function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is to create a service...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

Comment: Unlikely. In 99% of cases where people think they need to create a service, they're mistaken. There are lots of limitations associated with a Windows Service, and they usually end up biting people who created a service just because they wanted something to run without a UI. A standard Windows application that doesn't create/show a window is almost always a better and simpler approach.

Comment: Maybe, maybe... I was just highlighting another option.